# Spreadsheet to Google doc Table very long (4minutes)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Please help! It's a project so that by searching in the second column for 'o' (oui in French/ yes English) means that the project will be in 2019 so i will get the information from several columns i want(name project,date,chef de project...) from my Google Spreadsheet(at every time i find 'o' i will create a Google Doc file) and then put this information in a Google Doc Table already exists using a Template with makecopy() with 8 rows and 2 columns so all the information will be put in the second colum.In fact my code is very slow and if you have any ideas to improuve it will be great because it does the work in about 4 min

```js
function create_Google_Docs_2019_0() {
      
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,lastColumn).getValues()
    
      
      var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
      Logger.log('targetFolder name: ' + targetFolder.getName());
      
 
      var nombre_projets_2019 = 0 ;
      
      
      // the second row because the first is not important
       for(n=1;n < data.length;n++) {
        
        //verify if we have 'o' so we will create the corresponded document
         if ( data[n][1] == 'o'){
          nombre_projets_2019 = nombre_projets_2019  + 1;
          var name_projet = data[n][2];
           
          //var name_document = 'Projet ' + nom_projet ;
          var name_document = name_projet ;
          /** Search in the folder if we already have the file**/
          
          if( checkFile_in_a_Folder(name_document,targetFolder) == 1){
            //yeys we will update it later
            Logger.log('On va réecrire le ficher / overwrite le ficher ');
          } 
          else
          {//we will create it 
            Logger.log('On va le créer avec les données qu on a dans le tableau ');
            //Make a copy of the template file already exists in the file
            var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_DOC_ID).makeCopy().getId();
            
            //Rename the copied file
            var name = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(name_document);
            var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
            if(body)
            {
              var ok = 0;       //for instance we don't hava a table
              var numChildren=body.getNumChildren();
              var i=0;
              //we will loop
              while(ok ==0 && i<numChildren)
              {
                var child=body.getChild(i);
                /** =So we are concerned by the first table with 8 or more rows=========**/
                Logger.log('Le type dans la boucle  ' + child.getType());
                //if it's a table
                if(child.getType()==DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE && child.asTable().getNumRows() >= 8)
                {
                  //we found what we've searched
                  ok=1;   
                  
                  
  /** on va inserer les informations dans le tableau**/
                  
                  var k = 1;
                  child.asTable().getCell(0, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_nom_de_projet-1]);
                  child.asTable().getCell(1, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_code_de_projet-1] )  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(2, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_chef_de_projet-1])  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(3, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_service_pilote_de_projet-1] )  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(4, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_autres_services_projet-1] )  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(5, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_typede_projet-1] )  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(6, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_perimetre__projet-1] )  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(7, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_date_de_projet-1] )  ;
                }
                i++;
              }
            }
          } 
        }
        Logger.log('Nombre de projets 2019 ' +  nombre_projets_2019 );
      }
    }
```

I don't create the table in the Google Doc I get it from the Template so i search for the first children with 8 or more rows and the put the value in the right the big problem comes also from the sheet thank you

also for the constants i've declared at the first in the code

```
var colonne_nom_de_projet = 3
var colonne_code_de_projet = 1
var colonne_chef_de_projet = 7
var colonne_service_pilote_de_projet = 8
var colonne_autres_services_projet = 11
var colonne_typede_projet = 10
var colonne_perimetre__projet  = 12
var colonne_date_de_projet = 18
```

Edit edit: I have the impression that my post is not so clear so to explain this in images^^^^ in this google spreadsheet i have many column and [image: as here] and many rows 79 and i search the second colum for the 'o' means it will be a project for 2019 so in another folder which has a Google doc template [image: here] and i have a first table (8 rows) to put the information form an 'o' row with specific colums i am interested in (so i declared these columns as variables) so every time i copy the template and rename it with the name project in the 3rd column and then put the values so i will have files named b,c etc.

Comment: Can you try by moving the `documentId` and `body` declaration outside of the for loop? Also, try to take a look at [this blog](http://googleappsscript.blogspot.com/2010/06/optimizing-spreadsheet-operations.html) which talks about optimization

Comment: Thanks I don't get it how to move documentId and body declaration outside of the for loop you mean declare them as varibles because I need them in for as I have an 'o' means I will copy the template that already exists and access the body after that to put the values of the spreadsheet in the first table to complete the Google Doc

Comment: yes exactly, because looking at the code their value is not affected by a condition in the loop (right?). Simply something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2fxnp1bv/2/

Comment: Yes if fact I look for 'o' in the cell and if the value is present I will create a document (make copy of an already existing template) and fill it with the values in the row this is the purpose

Comment: I've tried your code but every time I have in the folder the Template and another document witch changes or I want every time I find 'o' create a new document sor if i have 40 'o' in the google Spreadsheet I will have 40 Google Docs corresponding filled with information form the Google Spreadsheet table

Comment: Thanks very much if you have others ideas it will be great :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Btw I understand now how it should work, I'll try to take a look later and let you know if I find other suggestions

Comment: I've edited my post with images because I had the impression it wasn't so clear